# Reduce the space between elements in modeline

Tags: elisp, mode-line

[image]

In the demo, there are 6 spaces between `main.c` (buffer name) and `[parse-early_param` (from `which-func`), 4 spaces between `which-func` and `53%`, and 2 or 3 spaces elsewhere. How can I set the space between them just 1 (or maybe 2) in order to save space in the mode line?

Comment: I can't write up a full answer right now, but for saving space in the mode-line you should have a look at smart-mode-line.

Comment: I do know [Smart-mode-line](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/smart-mode-line), but it's too much for me and I got my own configuration of mode line.

Answer (score 4):

See the Elisp manual, node [`%-Constructs`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/_0025_002dConstructs.html#g_t_0025_002dConstructs).  In particular, this part:

> In any construct except `%%`, you can add a decimal integer after
>   the `%` to specify a minimum field width.  If the width is less, the
>   field is padded to that width.  Purely numeric constructs (`c`, `i`,
>   `I`, and `l`) are padded by inserting spaces to the left, and others
>   are padded by inserting spaces to the right.

For the format of the mode line as a whole, see variable `mode-line-format`, which is covered in the manual at node [`Mode Line Format`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Format.html#Mode-Line-Format).

Generally, you do not modify `mode-line-format` directly, but you modify one or more of the variables that it uses as constituents.  These are covered in node [`Mode Line Variables`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Variables.html#Mode-Line-Variables).

You ask, in particular, about the space between what comes from variable `mode-line-buffer-identification` and what comes from variable `mode-line-modes`.  This is controlled by the right padding for the first of these variables.

For example, if `mode-line-buffer-identification` is `("%12b")` then if you change it to `("%1b")` the right padding will be reduced from 12 spaces to 1 space.

Answer (score 0):

To set the space between elements of your modeline, you just have to "type" the space key. For example, in this [modeline configuration](https://github.com/LeMeteore/emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/init_modeline.el), I use `" -- "` or `" "` to separate elements of my modeline.

This is one part of the setup, just to show you:

```
 ;; line and column
" -- ";;"[" ;; '%02' to set to 2 chars at least; prevents flickering
(propertize "%02l" 'face 'font-lock-type-face) ","
(propertize "%02c" 'face 'font-lock-type-face)
;;"] "
;; relative position, size of file
" -- "
(propertize "%p" 'face 'font-lock-constant-face) ;; % above top
" "
(propertize "%I" 'face 'font-lock-constant-face) ;; size
;;"] "
" "
```

Comment: You did set all the elements you want in mode line, but if you don't set it, it will not be shown in mode line(such as time value), how can I just change the specific element, such as I just want to change the buffer name's `propertize` , not the whole mode line?

Comment: You should first check the content of your current `mode-line-format` variable: `M-x describe-variable` then `mode-line-format`. In the buffer showing you the describe variable, there is a button for customization.

Comment: As the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Top.html#Mode-Line-Top) suggests. do not customize `mode-line-format`; just customize one or more of its component variables. In this case, variable `mode-line-buffer-identification` is probably all that is needed.